# XML edit replace/remove

Tags: c#, regex, xml, replace

I have an XML document I create with some data, it is always created in the same way, with the same amount of data, as seen in the following example:

```
<cac:Party>
  <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="Country">3023</cbc:EndpointID>
  <cac:PartyIdentification>
    <cbc:ID schemeID="Country">3023</cbc:ID>
  </cac:PartyIdentification>
  <cac:PartyName>
    <cbc:Name>Test</cbc:Name>
  </cac:PartyName>
  <cac:PostalAddress>
    <cbc:AddressFormatCode listAgencyID="###" listID="urn:oioubl:codelist:addressformatcode-1.1">StructuredLax</cbc:AddressFormatCode>
    <cbc:StreetName>Test</cbc:StreetName>
    <cbc:CityName>Test</cbc:CityName>
    <cbc:PostalZone>Test</cbc:PostalZone>
    <cac:Country>
      <cbc:IdentificationCode>DK</cbc:IdentificationCode>
    </cac:Country>
  </cac:PostalAddress>
  <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
    <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="Country">3023</cbc:CompanyID>
    <cac:TaxScheme>
      <cbc:ID schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:taxschemeid-1.1" schemeAgencyID="320">63</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:Name>Moms</cbc:Name>
    </cac:TaxScheme>
  </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
  <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    <cbc:RegistrationName>Test/cbc:RegistrationName>
    <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="Country">3023</cbc:CompanyID>
```

Now what I want is to edit the value: "3023" to "2020" (strings) but I only want to do it for the last one.

So far I've been trying to use "StreamReader + StreamWriter + Regex" as follows:

```
                        string docText = null;
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                        {
                            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        }

                        Regex oldValue = new Regex("3023");
                        docText = oldValue.Replace(docText, "2020");

                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
                        {
                            sw.Write(docText);
                        }
```

The obvious issue I run into here is that it changes it all the way through the document, so my thought was to maybe use substrings and find the specific index of the last "3023".
So because the document is always build the same way with the same amount of values, so I know the "3023" string I want is always the fourth one in the document, so I can find the starting index by using:

```
docText.IndexOf("3023", 4);
```

this gives me the starting index, I also know the number sequence is four letters "3023" this will always be the case, so therefore I can also find the ending index.

This is where I stall though, I am unsure what to make use of to then replace the string using indexes, there probably is a smarter method aswell, so I will happily take any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: This reminds of [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). Just use an XML parser, iterate the nodes (or use the DOM), and replace what you want.

Comment: Use something like Linq2XML. You can use `XDocument` to load the file, then descend to the right node and change it, then resave the XML

Comment: The XML sample is not a well-formed XML. It is missing namespaces declarations

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky This is not the full XML document, simply a snippet. Also all areas that say "test" is simply me hiding some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(INPUT_FILENAME);
            XElement CompanyID = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "CompanyID").Last();
            CompanyID.Value = "2020";
            doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME);
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Very nice, made a small adjustment where I added XElement to list and added a counter through a "for each" statement, which allowed me to change at specific points, but it works perfectly fine, thanks.